# Downloading Image with Python Telegram API

Tags: python, telegram

I followed their brief tutorial on downloading an image but I'm encountering an exception:

> telegram.photosize.PhotoSize object at ... is not JSON serializable

the function for catching the images looks like this:

```
def photo(bot, update):
   file_id = update.message.photo[-1]
   newFile = bot.getFile(file_id)
   newFile.download('test.jpg')
   bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="download succesfull")

photo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo)
dispatcher.add_handler(photo_handler)
```

The Exception occurs while getting the file.
I have tried all kinds of files however im was not succesful with the download.

At this point I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and can't find any solution on the net.

Comment: Which framework you are using?

Comment: Im using the framework from https://python-telegram-bot.org